# How to make a 2D game objects to move down constantly

Tags: android, 2d

i'm planning to make a 2D android game , which will need an infinite movement to the top direction, how can i make the "flying" objects to continue going down so it will look like the main object of the game is going up , 
I was thinking of making an 2D array that will be moving by rows and column and it will make it look like the game is moving up , 
but i don't think its a good way to do it and i would be glad to get any tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do everything yourself, this is a little example how you can start:

```
public class FlyingObjects {

  private Vec2d position;
  private Vec2d velocity;

  public FlyingObjects(Vec2d pos, Vec2d velo) {
    position = pos;
    velocity = velo;
  }
  void step(float delta){
    position.x += velocity.x * delta;
    position.y += velocity.y * delta;
  }
}
```

You have a Class for your FlyingObjects.
When you need more than one Flying Objects you can do this as an Interface an Inherit it in all of your Flying Objects classes.

```
public class Main {

  static List<FlyingObjects> listOfObjectsFlyingDown = new ArrayList<>();
  private static long lastCall;

  public static void main(String[] args){
    initialization();
    lastCall = System.currentTimeMillis();
    run();
  }
  private static void initialization(){
    //add FlyingObjects to List
  }

  private static void run(){
    float delta = System.currentTimeMillis() - lastCall; //delta is the time between this and the last call of this function
    lastCall = System.currentTimeMillis();

    for(FlyingObjects o: listOfObjectsFlyingDown){
      o.step(delta);
    }
    //check collision
    //check mouse and Keyboard event
    //check if FlyingObjects position is out of the window so remove it
    //repaint screen

    run();
  }
}
```

This is a little example for the main gameloop you need. In this loop you make all your importend stuff which has to be updated every frame.

If you do not want to do the hole physics from scratch give a look at jbox2d:
http://www.jbox2d.org/
And when you want a game development framework for Android which is good for beginners, give also a look at libgdx: https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/

I hope I could help you